# How to create user-accounts' separate folders to save user data in--PHP

Tags: php, user-accounts

How would I save each user's 'default photo' onto a website? This same photo may be used during some of their interactions on the site(maybe in a chat session), and it may be displayed on their profile page.  Will each user have their own folder? If so, how can I create such a folder. Will this folder stay on ftp? Or MySQL? Will it take any space? As of now, whatever photos are uploaded onto the server, are simply stored in a folder that reads--**'uploadportrait.php'**. Where can I go from this? If someone can tell me the general principles of this, then that would be great! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just one photo it doesn't make much sense to create a folder for each user. If you already have a working upload routine, simply store the file path of the uploaded file inside of the user database. You don't need to duplicate the image then.